# Integrating Sagepay (Opayo) with Django - How to create a merchant session key

Tags: django, curl, opayo

I am trying to integrate Opayo (SagePay) with Django and I am having problems generation the merchant session key (MSK).

From sagepays docs they say to use the below curl request and that I should receive the key in the response

```
curl https://pi-test.sagepay.com/api/v1/merchant-session-keys \
-H "Authorization: Basic aEpZeHN3N0hMYmo0MGNCOHVkRVM4Q0RSRkxodUo4RzU0TzZyRHBVWHZFNmhZRHJyaWE6bzJpSFNyRnliWU1acG1XT1FNdWhzWFA1MlY0ZkJ0cHVTRHNocktEU1dzQlkxT2lONmh3ZDlLYjEyejRqNVVzNXU="  \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-X POST \
-d '{
  "vendorName": "sandbox"
}'
```

I have tried to implement this in my Django view with the following code but I receive a 422 response (Unprocessable Entity response).

```
import requests

def BasketView(request): 
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic aEpZeHN3N0hMYmo0MGNCOHVkRVM4Q0RSRkxodUo4RzU0TzZyRHBVWHZFNmhZRHJyaWE6bzJpSFNyRnliWU1acG1XT1FNdWhzWFA1MlY0ZkJ0cHVTRHNocktEU1dzQlkxT2lONmh3ZDlLYjEyejRqNVVzNXU=",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
    }
    data = {"vendorName": "sandbox"}

    r = requests.post("https://pi-test.sagepay.com/api/v1/merchant-session-keys", headers=headers, params=data)
    print(r)
```

Any ideas where I may be going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the wrong parameter to `requests.post()` you should use `json`instead of `params`:

```py
r = requests.post(
    "https://pi-test.sagepay.com/api/v1/merchant-session-keys",
    headers=headers,
    json=data
)
```

By doing so, there is no need to specify the `Content-Type` header, it is added automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much Thom, that worked perfectly. I spent half of the day trying to solve this!